# Decoding special characters in cart (custom options message)

Tags: cart, magento-1.9.1.1

Customers can enter their own custom message that will be added to the product. Everything works fine, **except the special characters are encoded in the cart**. I can't seem to find a way to fix this (where to put the decode) so any help is very welcome!

The url called to add product to the cart: `/checkout/cart/add/product/` + url with parameters

[image: encoded special characters in cart]

Thanks!
Klemen

Comment: Are you using an extension or a custom theme to manage that? If so, verify the encoding of the files used.

Comment: @JulienLachal Thanks a lot mate. You put me in the right direction. I checked the custom theme files and applied urldecode() to the options displayed.

Comment: np mate, please put your solution as an answer and accept it so as your question doesn't hang around unanswered ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was in checking **custom theme cart files** and **applying urldecode();** to the options displayed there.

[image: urldecode applied]